# Canvas App - Allowness issue for the run-only users

Tags: power-automate, powerapps-canvas

I have created a canvas app in the `Tenant A`, and created a canvas app + MS flow with that domain's users.

Now, I want to deploy this canvas app on the different tenant i.e., `Tenant B` - where a specific team should be able to access this canvas app and the integrated flow with it without `allowness` to be popped up asking for sign in for that data connections.

Here, consider below example:

> **Tenant A login**: pratik.soni@tenantA.com
> `This user is not added as external user in <<Tenant B>>`

> **Tenant B Login**: developer@tenantB.com

To achieve that - I have set the `Run only User` to the particular team. Refer below screenshot:
[image]

**What is the actual issue?**

> When user runs the canvas app for the first time - system automatically creates a new `Connection` in Power Apps and not using the actual once from the `Tenant A` as displayed above.
> [image]

> [image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe the only way to do this is to have a Flow call a Child flow.

```
PA --> Flow A --> Flow B
```

Flow A has no connections defined, and so PowerApp won't ask for any.
Flow B has the connections and set to Run-As as you have above.

Comment: Tried this, but not working either. Still asking for the "allowness"

Comment: That shouldn't be, are there any connections within the PowerApp itself? And double check there are no connections defined (or left behind) in the parent flow (Flow A).

Comment: Yes, there is connection within canvas app - but those connections are already shared with the whole organization. So `Sign In` is  not asked for those.

Comment: Are there any connections listed in Flow A (parent flow) in the Flow details page (top right box)?

Comment: No, there is none